# Python Pandas - Merging on Substring Issues

Tags: pandas, merge

I am trying to merge 3 columns from one dataframe to another on the **SKU** column.

The trickey part is that the string values in the DF1 SKU column and DF2 SKU column are different,
To solve this I need to check to see if the string in the DF1 SKU column is a substring within the DF2 SKU column and merge on that.

**MAIN ISSUE**
The main issue is that although my code seems to work it always populates data in the **SKU Match** column which you can see in the 3rd DF below.
(i.e. if the The substring can't be matched it will populate the SKU from DF2).

**However** What I want is where the SKUs cannot be matched I want a blank field in the SKU Match column.

Hope this makes sense

**DF1**

| SKU | Region |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | A |
| CCC | C |
| C12g | D |
| DD | E |
| R9D | F |
| dfg4 | G |
| asfdh5 | H |
| 45gh | I |
| DFHDHF | J |

**DF2**

| SKU | Company | ID | Platform |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAxx1 | Microsoft | 1002165100651 | OS |
| AAxxREG1 | Apple | 5918992355452 | OS |
| BBBER4 | Microsoft | 5619849849185 | OS |
| CCCERG | Dell | 9917815102151 | Storage |
| C12g88 | Dell | 6616541501205 | Storage |
| DFHDHF | Facebook | 1418961620151 | Social Media |

**Desired Output**

Where SKU from DF1 is in the SKU column of DF2 I want to add the company, ID and Platform columns to DF1

| SKU | Region | Company | SKU Match | ID | Platform |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | A | Microsoft | AAA | 1002165100651 | OS |
| CCC | C | Dell | CCC | 9917815102151 | Storage |
| C12g | D | Dell | C12g | 6616541501205 | Storage |
| DD | E |  |  |  |  |
| R9D | F |  |  |  |  |
| dfg4 | G |  |  |  |  |
| asfdh5 | H |  |  |  |  |
| 45gh | I |  |  |  |  |
| DFHDHF | J | Facebook | DFHDHF | 1418961620151 | Social Media |

**Current code**

```
# Create a SKU ID list with the list of SKUs from DF2 and Match them to DF1.
# Then use this list to merge the Company, ID and Platform columns from DF2 to DF1.
key = DF1['SKU'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(sorted(DF2['SKU'].values, key=len, reverse=True))})", expand=False)



# Merge The data from DF2 to DF1
DF1 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2[['Company','ID ','Platform']], left_on=['SKU'],right_on=[key], how='left').drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df2['SKU Match'] = df2['SKU'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(df1['SKU'])})")
out = df1.merge(df2.drop(columns='SKU'), left_on='SKU', right_on='SKU Match',
                how='left').fillna('')
print(out)

# Output
      SKU Region    Company             ID      Platform SKU Match
0     AAA      A  Microsoft  1002165100651            OS       AAA
1     CCC      C       Dell  9917815102151       Storage       CCC
2    C12g      D       Dell  6616541501205       Storage      C12g
3      DD      E                                                  
4     R9D      F                                                  
5    dfg4      G                                                  
6  asfdh5      H                                                  
7    45gh      I                                                  
8  DFHDHF      J   Facebook  1418961620151  Social Media    DFHDHF
```